# How to connect Android Studio & ESP WROOM 02 (ESP8266)?

Tags: android, wifi, esp8266

First time post here, I am new to programming with android studio. I am not sure if I came to the right place to ask for help. I am not sure what I am trying to do is possible or where to search for tutorials on the subject. I don't have experience with connecting devices over WiFi at all.

Here is what I am trying to do:
I have an App I created with Android Studio, this app has a list of "devices", these devices will control a window over a wifi connection.
In the app, I simply have an "Open" button and a "Close" button for each "device".

I need to be able to show that the 'device' (which is the wifi stepper below) is connected to my app.

I am using the ESP-WROOM-02 (ESP8266) wifi module. Specifically, this wifi-stepper: https://www.crowdsupply.com/good-robotics/wi-fi-stepper

I can give more info or code samples of my project if needed, and any help is much appreciated. I don't know how or where to start.

tldr; I am unsure how to program the connection between the app and the module so that when I press open, the window will open.

Comment: First question are you expecting the Android Device running the App and ESP chip to be in wifi range of each other or both be connected to the internet via wifi?

Comment: They will both be connected to the internet via WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

Update, As now you say they are both on the same network and the device says "HTTP(S) JSON RESTful interface" you app just needs to make https requests to the ip address of the device.

Docs https://bitbucket.org/aklofas/wifistepper/src/master/documentation/src/interfaces/restful.md

And in Android one method of http requests https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

The device has fairly good documentation of how to set it all up and talk to it via it's various interfaces.

Comment: I have purchased a router to act as an access point for both devices. But I don’t know much about setting up the connection of each device (the android phone and the WiFi stepper) to the access point and then communication between them programmatically. 

In theory I want to be able to see that the device(WiFi stepper) is connected on the app.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the restful interface, i will have to research it more then. Thank you.